# Can I search a folder for phrases contained within files (from the Windows command line)?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Background: I have programming experience, but have not programmed in years.

My place of employment (a State prison) does not allow me to download programming tools/environments (internet access is severely curtailed).

I need to search the contents of a folder for phrases contained within files contained within that folder. For example, in a given (network) folder, I want to search all the MS Word docs in the folder for a phrase such as "knee brace."

Is there a way to do this -- at the command line, for example (assuming such is still available in Windows 10)? All I would need is the name of which file[s] contained the phrase provided.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the command prompt is certainly still a viable solution in Windows 10.  Either run cmd or right click the start menu to find it.

[this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/206097/how-to-use-find-from-the-windows-command-prompt/amp/) appears like it may be able to help you.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`findstr`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr) command. For example:

```
C:\...> findstr /S /C:"knee brace" * | more
```

The `/S` option will search the current directory and all sub-directories. If you want to save the results to a file, you can use [command redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```
C:\...> findstr /S /C:"/knee brace" * > results.txt
```

Comment: For a network folder, does the "/C:" still apply? If not, what should that look like? Something like "///bla/bla/bla"? (I won't be able to try it out until Monday at the earliest)

Answer (score 1):

To search Word documents, I think you'll need some scripting. PowerShell is Windows built-in command/scripting environment. A great example is [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ac425760-beb9-442f-9651-41428e23fc41/powershell-script-to-find-a-string-in-word-document-and-move-to-other-location-if-exists?forum=winserverpowershell).

Keith

Comment: Would "source" be something like this for a network folder:

Comment: $source = '\\source' // instead of: $source = 'D:\source' ?

Comment: Yes. See the first answer at https://serverfault.com/questions/549040/access-network-share-without-mapping-drive-letter-powershell